# How can I capture and compare subset of value from different arrays?

Tags: perl, arrays

I have 10 arrays, each consisting of similar type of values. I want to capture a subset of these values (capture only the digits) from each array and then compare it with a subset from another array. And also, I want to capture the number part of values from both arrays only when there is no *dash* in the value (i.e., 2EF = capture '2', but if 45F- then not capture anything, move to the next value).

_ *DATA* _

@array1 = (-, 1EF, 2DG, 3GF, 4F-, -, ....99GY);

@array2 = (-, 1EF, 2DF, 3SD, 4DE, -, ....99HK);

Any two arrays out of 10 can be compared at a time. So, I have stored them in an array, '`@allarrays`', and loop it to compare. In the following script, I am able to capture the digit of the first array perfectly, but I am unable to compare digits from the second array. The value of $digit1 (corresponding to @array1) gets copied into $digit2 (corresponding to @array2). what’s going wrong?

```
sub compareArrays {
    my @array = @_; # passes an array @allarray which has @array1, @array2 ...@array10

    for (my $p=0; $p<10; $p++) { # since total number of arrays is 10
        for (my $r=$p + 1; $r<10; $r++) { # to compare arrays
            for (my $q=0; $q<$colsInArray; $q++) {
                my $string1 = $array[$p][$q];
                my $string2 = $array[$r][$q];

                # array1
                $string1 =~ /(\d+)[A-Z]+/;

                my $digit1 = $1; # capture digit part of array value
                print "array1: $digit1\n"; # works fine, prints captured $digit1

                # array2
                $string2 =~ /(\d+)[A-Z]+/;
                my $digit2 = $1;
                print "array2: $digit2\n"; # does not capture the value in $digit2, instead copies $digit1

                if ($digit1 == $digit2) {
                    print "$digit1: $digit2\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling compareArrays as:

```
&compareArrays(@allarrays);
```

Comment: And what is @allarrays set to?  Since what you have posted basically works, you're going to need to post a full runnable example, including initializing the arrays, for us to see what part isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use your test code, it does capture the value in $digit2.  You might show us how you are calling compareArrays.

You should check if the regex matched before accessing $1; if the regex failed, $1 will be left over from the previous match.  You don't have anything to skip values containing -.
Assuming the digits are always at the beginning, followed by only uppercase letters, you could combine both those by saying

```
my ($digit1) = $string1 =~ /^([0-9]+)[A-Z]+\z/ or next;
```

Comment: @ysth: I commented everything for $digit1 to see if regex for $digit2 works. On printing $digit2, it is clear that the regex is working. But, when I combine then $digit2 has the same value as $digit1. I have also updated on how I am calling compareArrays.

Comment: @ysth: I replaced $string1=~ /(\d+)[A-Z]+/; my $digit1 = $1; with what you wrote above. Replacing it with your expression seems to solve the purpose. But, I am not sure why? Anyway, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass an array to a subroutine, you must pass by reference:

```
compareArrays(\@allarrays);
```